# egit replacing single file - HEAD Revision vs File in git index

Tags: eclipse, git, egit, git-reset

In the egit git eclipse plugin, I know I can "reset" a single file by right clicking on it and selecting Replace With > HEAD Revision. What is the difference between replacing with HEAD revision vs File in git index?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

`HEAD` is the version of the file that has already been committed.

The index is the version of the file that has been staged (added) in preparation for a commit, but not yet committed.

Comment: i.e. "replace with `HEAD`" is like saying "revert to last committed version of this file" ?

Comment: "revert to last committed version of this file" (in your local repo)